# Using javascript getTimezoneOffset to get local time of the client with C# backend

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I need to capture the timezone offset of the client and store it in my database. To do this I have been using a hidden field in the login with some Javascript :

```
<form class="user" id="account" method="post">
    <input asp-for="Input.TimezoneOffset" type="hidden" />
....
</form>

$(document).ready(function () {

    var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
    document.getElementById("Input_TimezoneOffset").value = offset;
});
```

Then I store this value in a string session variable and whenever I need to convert a utc datetime from the database to display to the end user I use this code to convert the string to the local time :

```
public static DateTime ConvertUTCToLocalDateTime(DateTime utcDateTime, string timezoneOffset)
{
    TimeSpan offSet = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(timezoneOffset));
    DateTime localTime = utcDateTime - offSet;

    return localTime;
}
```

So far this is all working nicely. My question is, is this a reliable way to do this, or is there a better way?

Comment: You should save UTC time and let the browser display it based on the locale.

Comment: What I came up with, after research on SO some weeks ago was `console.log(new Date().toLocaleString("de-DE", {timeZone:'Europe/Berlin'}))` . You need this for that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any hidden dom element.
This could be done directly in JS...

be care about daylight saving time...

js code

```
const fetchInfo =
  { method      : 'POST'
  , mode        : 'same-origin'
  , credentials : 'same-origin'
  , headers     : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  , body        : `{"TimezoneOffset": ${new Date().getTimezoneOffset()}}`
  };

fetch( 'server/url' , fetchInfo)
 .then(res=>{ console.log("fetch complete! response:", res);});
```

code for test test:

```js
let 
  TZ_Offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()  * -1
, minutes  = TZ_Offset  % 60
, hours    = (TZ_Offset - minutes) / 60
, formated =  'UTC '+(TZ_Offset<0?String.fromCharCode(8722):'+') 
           + String(hours).padStart(2, '0') + ':'
           + String(minutes).padStart(2, '0')
  ;
console.log( 'your actual time zone offset is = ' + formated );
```

Comment: I need to have access to the value in the backend in C#, that is why I did it the way I did

Comment: @user517406  so just add an AJAX call to send this value to your server.

Comment: @user517406 I have updated my answer with the ajax code..

Comment: I think having a complete separate request for this is bad practice. Especially since the view has all the necessary data on initialisation.